# Review Board default sender email

Tags: review-board

[Review Board documentation](https://www.reviewboard.org/docs/manual/2.0/admin/configuration/email/#sending-e-mail) mentions that

> Sender Headers
>
> Review Board can send e-mail on behalf of users. This may happen when creating a new review request or reviewing some code.
>
> E-mails appear to be sent from the users, rather than from Review Board itself.
>
> ...
>
> By using these two fields instead of just faking the From address, we can avoid e-mails appearing to be spam or otherwise malicious. Many modern e-mail clients warn if the From address appears to be suspicious.

Is there any way to disable email sending on behalf of users? I want to send emails from default email which is set in the admin panel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the `from_email` in

https://github.com/reviewboard/reviewboard/blob/0935f8daf9b2f07d1f679a1cbed49998df3d59de/reviewboard/notifications/email.py

for the method:

```
def send_review_mail(user, review_request, subject, in_reply_to,
                     to_field, cc_field, text_template_name,
                     html_template_name, context=None, extra_headers=None)
```

In particular, the line:
`from_email = get_email_address_for_user(user)`

We do something similar for our server setup at the company to force the sender to be a particular user that we want users to respond to.